# Can't nest links in html5?

Tags: javascript, css, html

In xhtml I usually nest lists, close the  tag then begin a new  before the closing  tag. This technique makes a the list structure clear when rendered without any css and it's a convenient structure for applying JS to.

Today I come up against a problem nesting links in a html5 document:

```
<header>
   <nav>
       <a href="#">A link</a>
       <a href="#">A link
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">nested link</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">nested link</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">nested link</a></li>
           </ul>
       </a>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Which doesn't work. The nested list is nested in another a tag.

So a technique I used regularly in xhtml doesn't work in html5. My question is what do you do in the situation where you want to create a flyout menu? Is there a technique I can use in html5 to make it as easy as it is in xhtml? I know I can create this flyout menu without nested links but I liked the conciseness of the old method.

Comment: When would you ever need that? What behavior are you looking for? An anchor is suppose to make everything inside it clickable, how would you know what Area is what?

Comment: As far as I was aware, nesting anchor tags is invalid XHTML as well. [The spec seems to agree](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions), from what I can find (XHTML 1.1 does not appear to have changed this part of the spec).

Comment: @eldarerathis — technically it isn't invalid (since the XML DTDs can't express "Cannot have an `a` as a descendent at any level"), but it is non-conforming.

Comment: Apologies. I think I may have put the question badly. I've re-phrased it.

Comment: @FilipEkberg: Here's why you might need it. Say you have a bunch of divs on a homepage, each representing another page on your site. Each one has an image, a label, and a headline. HTML5 lets you wrap each whole div in an `<a>` element linking to the relevant page. But what if you want to make that label in the middle also clickable (to take you to a page listing all pages with that label)? HTML5 currently forbids this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build your menu structure in nested lists, and have the first element in every list be a link. Works just fine and you can make it look right in CSS.

Comment: Thanks. Basically I thought in html5 the proper way to use the nav element was to put use links (no ul or li's) in it. I've since found that it's prefectly acceptable to use an ul inside the nav element so I can keep on coding as before

Answer (score 3):

I [never want to make a flyout menu](http://message.uk.com/dropdown-menus-no-thanks), but if a client cannot be convinced otherwise then:

- The list of links at the top level would be represented as a list, not a bunch of anchors directly under the nav element
- I would structure the DOM so a submenu would be represented as a list that appeared *after* a link, and not inside it.
- I would use JavaScript to handle the opening/closing since `:hover` is inadequate as it:

  - doesn't work with keyboard access or
  - allow time to pass after the point leaves the menu before closing it (it is hard not to wobble across the edges for some people, e.g. those with arthritis)

Comment: Your last points are wrong; while `:hover` is mouse-only, `:focus` does brook keyboard accessibility (though you'll have to be slightly careful how you manage it to get a fully accessible arrangement); as for allowing time to pass before closing the menu, that is no longer a problem; you can use a transition with delay to overcome that.